# How to have text in the border of a div?

Tags: html, css

I have created a div where I am trying to showcase some certifications I have earned and I want to show the position on top of the border. But I am failing to figure out how to do that.
I want to do something like this[image]

I have made Everything shown in the pic above except the `3rd place` text on top of the border/div.
how can I do that?

This is the HTML code I've done so far

```
<div class="col-lg-4 certifications-border" >

                <center>

                <img class="certifications-image" src="assets/images/certification-images/imagineCupLogo.jpg" alt="">

                <h3>Imagine Cup</h3>
                <hr/>
                <p>lorem ipsum text generated</p>
              </center>
            </div>
```

css code

```
  .certifications h3{
    text-align: center;
}

.certifications-image{

    position: relative;

    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 50%;

    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;

    border-radius: 10px;
 }


 .certifications hr{

    border-color:#68c3a3;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom:5px; margin-bottom:5px; 

}

.certifications p{
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}

.certifications-border{

    border: 2px solid #68c3a3;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;

}
```

Also, if I add 3 divs to show them next to each other, they show up in line, but if I add some speace between them (`margin`) one of them falls down. now I understand why this happens, but I am not sure what to do to fix it, possible help for this too?

Comment: Do you have a CSS file to share?

Comment: it is just basic stuff, that is why didn't include. But I'll use it anyway. by the time you are reading it it is uploaded

Comment: Scroll up to the top of the page.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x5cqdbz6/ a little help to you ;) enjoy

Comment: oh my apologies, didn't recognize it. Also, there's a 2nd question for the divs, is there a possible answer for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of seems like what you want. You probably need to style it with css though. Another tip: `<center>` tags are html4 tags, it would be better to use another `<div>` and style it with css instead of the `<center>` tags. Anyways I hope this helps.

```css
.certifications h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.certifications-image {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.certifications hr {
  border-color: #68c3a3;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.certifications p {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.certifications-border {
  border: 2px solid #68c3a3;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 certifications-border">
  <p>3rd Place</p>
  <center>
    <img class="certifications-image" src="assets/images/certification-images/imagineCupLogo.jpg" alt="">

    <h3>Imagine Cup</h3>
    <hr/>
    <p>lorem ipsum text generated</p>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: The text is under the border, not at the border. What I am trying to do is to get it in between the border. I could fake it with something like ``top: -10px`` but how can I hide the border behind?

Comment: The border should hide automatically.

Comment: @BTEK You could add a background color to the element that is on the edge of the border that would cover up the border.